# Hibernate IndexEmbedded Spatial Entities

Tags: lucene, jpa-2.0, spatial, hibernate-search, hibernate-spatial

## **The Scenario**

Class Employee, Class Office, Class OfficeEmployee.

**Class office** is a Spatial Entity, that can be searched and returns results as expected.

a manyToMany relationship between Office-Employee is mapped with the Class **OfficeEmplyee**.

Now I need to perform search based on certain people within some range. in other words I have to check for the offices in range and for emplyees who exist at those offices, i.e Searching the **OfficeEmployee** Entity.

All the three classes are indexed.

## **OfficeEmployee**

```
// reference Spatial indexed entity Office
@IndexedEmbedded
@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="office")
private  Office office; 


// reference to employee
@IndexedEmbedded
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="employee")
private  Employee employee;
```

## **Class Office**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@Spatial(name = "office_location_poi", spatialMode = SpatialMode.HASH )
@Indexed
@Entity
@Embeddable

public class Office implements Serializable,Coordinates {

    // some attributes , getters , setters..



    @ContainedIn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="office", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OfficeEmployee > officeEmployees;


    @Latitude
    double latitude;

    @Longitude
    double longitude;
    public Coordinates getLocation() {
      return new Coordinates() {
        @Override
        public Double getLatitude() {
          return latitude;
        }

        @Override
        public Double getLongitude() {
          return longitude;
        }
      };
    }




    @Override
    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

}
```

## **The Query:**

```
final QueryBuilder builder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                     .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( OfficeEmployee.class ).get();

double centerLatitude = searchTerm.lat;
double centerLongitude =searchTerm.lng;  


org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery =  builder.spatial().onField("office").within(searchTerm.distance, Unit.KM)
                  .ofLatitude(centerLatitude)
                  .andLongitude(centerLongitude)
               .createQuery();

org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery hibQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, OfficeEmployee.class);

// sort             
Sort distanceSort = new Sort(
                new DistanceSortField(centerLatitude, centerLongitude, "office_location_poi"));
hibQuery.setSort(distanceSort);  
hibQuery.setProjection(FullTextQuery.SPATIAL_DISTANCE, FullTextQuery.THIS);
hibQuery.setFirstResult(0);
hibQuery.setMaxResults(20);
// results           
List<Office>results =hibQuery.getResultList();
```

## **The Problem**

Now I want to perform my search on the relationship table (OfficeEmployee).

but sounds like I can't get it to work! I checked tutorials, and couldn't find such an example.

- Is it possible to use a currently indexed Entity like I have explained?
- Do I have to include a @Spatial there in the OfficeEmployee ? but that will require a new indexing separately, I want to use the currently indexed one.
- When I run search it says that I need to check @Spatial and @SpatialFieldBridge, and even if I annotate so, the results are empty.
- In case that my Spatial entity was implementing the coordinates and doesn't have a separate field for coordinates, where should the @ContainedIn be placed ?

Can anyone please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: I don't understand your domain model to start with. Why would you need a dedicated OfficeEmployee entity? Why not just Employee and Office? Also you are saying you get an error/exception? How does this look like?

Comment: Thank you @Hardy, the employee may belong/exist in more than one location, and the office can have more than one employee, in other words the relation is manytoMany due to this specification. As a design pattern we decided to go with a separate table OfficeEmployee. The exception I received was from Hibernate telling that the usage of the embeded Index was not correct. I couldn't find one example explaining how to embed and already indexed entity(Spatial) in such a situation.

Comment: You can map a many-to-many association just by using set with `@ManyToMany`; This will create the required intermediary table automatically, no need to map this one to an entity unless your association is meant to have additional attributes itself.